# Sum respective column values given in particular column in two tables

Tags: r

I have One table as header and values as below:

```
Salesman    Invoice.No  Invoice.Amount  Collection.Amount
Ashish      1040             1050            399
Ashish      1041             2500            2100
Ashish      1041             2500            100
Ashish      1040             1050            500
```

Aggregate Function

```
New_Data = aggregate(Pending_Inv$Collection.Amount, by=list(Invoice.no=Pending_Inv$Invoice.No), FUN=sum)
```

Need to know the collection amount against the each Invoice no and Pending Amount (subtracting from Invoice Amount)

Comment: Would `Invoice.Amount` be same for every `Invoice.No` ? What would your expected output look like?

Comment: No its different for every invoice

Answer (score 0):

An idea using `dplyr` can be to group by salesman & invoice number and simply do the calculations. The trick here I think is to declare the `invoice.amount` within the aggregation, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% 
 group_by(Salesman, Invoice.No) %>% 
 summarise(total = sum(Collection.Amount), 
           Invoice.Amount = first(Invoice.Amount), 
           outstanding = Invoice.Amount - total)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 5
> # Groups:   Salesman [1]
>   Salesman Invoice.No total Invoice.Amount outstanding
>   <fct>         <int> <int>          <int>       <int>
> 1 Ashish         1040   899           1050         151
> 2 Ashish         1041  2200           2500         300
> ```

Comment: @AjayYadav Please go ahead and accept this answer by clicking the checkmark next to it so we can consider this question closed. Thanks